# Can I configure my .cshrc to ignore all files with a certain extension?

Tags: file-extension, tcsh

For the most part, I really don't care whether `*.pyc` files exist. I don't want them to show up when I do `ls`. I don't want them to be part of tab-completion. Basically, I want my shell to treat them exactly like it treats, for example, `.gitignore` or any other dot file.

Is there some tweak where I can continue using the shell like I currently do, but just not see this clutter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for the completion:

> The shell variable fignore can be set to a list of suffixes to be ignored by completion.

The following example will ignore all *.pyc *.o *.bak and *~ files.

```
% set fignore = (.pyc .o .bak \~)
```

For the 'ls' you can use the --ignore argument, better inside an alias.

```
% alias ls 'ls --color --ignore="*.pyc"'
```